# MessageService declared undefined even though it is injected into ErrorService constructor

Tags: angular

I have an authentication service that calls an error service when an error occurs:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private loginUrl:string = '/api/auth/login';

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient, private errorService:ErrorService) { }

  public login(credentials) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(credentials);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.loginUrl, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorService.handleError)
    )
  }
}
```

The ErrorService calls the MessageService which adds the error message to the messages array that is displayed in the message view.

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {

 constructor(private messageService:MessageService) { }

  public handleError(error: Response | any) {
    this.messageService.add('ERROR MESSAGE');
    return of([])
  }
}
```

MessageService is injected into the constructor of ErrorService as seen above. But MessageService is declared undefined when the handleError function of ErrorService invokes the messageService.add() funciton in the line of code shown above:

```
this.messageService.add('ERROR MESSAGE');
```

It produces the following error:

```
core.js:1624 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at AuthService.push../src/app/shared/error/error.service.ts.ErrorService.handleError (error.service.ts:25)
at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
```

MessageService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {
  public messages: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  add(message:string) {
    this.messages.push(message);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clear();
    }, 20000)
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan MessageService added

Comment: Without the .bind(this), is it still not working?

Comment: can you post the order you have injected in app.module.ts

Comment: can you remove "providedIn: 'root'" and then give it a try. You shouldn't get that error at runtime if the service doesn't give a compile error.

Comment: @Wandrille yes, without the bind(this) it is still not working.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I did not register either service in app.module. The "providedIn: 'root'" in the Injectable decorator handles the registration automatically.

Comment: Can you do a console.log(this) in ErrorService? And can you please, add just the module.ts (just the providers). Thanks
EDIT: I have seen your answer.

Comment: @Wandrille ErrorService log(this) 
CatchSubscriber {closed: false, _parent: Subscriber, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
caught
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: CatchOperator}
closed
:
true
destination
:
Subscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
isStopped
:
true
selector
:
ƒ (error)
syncErrorThrowable
:
true
syncErrorThrown
:
false
syncErrorValue
:
null
_parent
:
null
_parents
:
null
_subscriptions
:
null
__proto__
:
OuterSubscriber

Comment: @windmaomao If I remove providedIn: 'root', I will then have to register the service in app.module.ts. Is that what you are asking? And do mean remove it from ErrorService or MessageService?

Comment: 'this' doesnt sound to refer to ErrorService. The error comes from here.